# Signatures do not match - trying to test an update

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am currently seeing this error:

```
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: 
Package signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
```

This is an assembly error that Android developers often see when their application is already installed on the device. Often, the solution is to simply uninstall the version from the device.

In my case, I have the latest version of the app available on the Play Store installed. I am looking to test a new version using data stored in the app (from React Native's `AsyncStorage`), and want to ensure the update smoothly reads this existing data when the app is updated with the new version.

I have assembled a new release APK with a new version name, and incremented the version code by one. The APK was assembled using the same signing configuration as the version that is on the Play Store.

If I understand correctly, I should not see this error. Shouldn't the signatures match because both APKs used the same signing config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publicly available APK from Google Play is signed with Google's certificates.

To get around this, I accessed the the artifact library available through the Google Play console and downloaded the original APK.

I then installed the original APK to the device using `adb install original.apk`. This allowed me to install the new version as an update without seeing the 'signatures do not match' error.